# Python - Download image from direct link (Forbidden, You don't have permission to access on this server)

Tags: python, image, cookies

I need to download an image through Python (can't post the url since I think the content type is not allowed here).

The image is loaded in a page, so I first get the image direct url from the page source code with BeautifoulSoup and then try do download it with:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlretrieve(image, folder)
```

which usually works fine, but it doesn't work on this server.

If I open the page with the image in my browser and then copy the image direct link in another browser window and open it, I get the image, but if I try to directly open the image in another window without first opening the webpage where the image is, I get the error 403:

> **Forbidden** You don't have permission to access /1.jpg on this server.

Direct opening the image still works if I close the browser and re-open it, but if I change the browser I get error 403 again.

I thought it could be something cookie-releated, so I've tried:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(PAGE_WITH_IMAGE)
cookie = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
req2 = urllib2.Request(DIRECT_LINK_TO_IMAGE)
req2.add_header('cookie', cookie)
urllib2.urlretrieve(req2, folder)
```

But I still get error 403.

Comment: Sound like the server has some kind of direct download protection. But that's just a guess since you did not say which server it is.

Comment: Is there a User Login?

Comment: No login. I can direct access the image, but only if I've opened at least once the page where the image is (like if is the page to request the image at first, then I'm allowed to access it even by direct link). The server is adult content I don't think I can post the link. Is there any test I can do that would help?

Comment: Maybe try assigning a requests.session() and use the same session object to get both of those links?

Comment: Depending on the quality you are looking for, you could screen shot it with selenium webdriver.